# Where does Keynote store the recorded slideshow?

Tags: audio, video, keynote, quicktime

I have a similar problem to [this person on the Apple discussion board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8008272)

> I spent almost 60 hours building, narrating and editing a Keynote presentation only to find that when I export the file to Quicktime, the audio isn't included. Its a silent film

The advice given in that thread has not worked for me.

The presentation already has all the sounds embedded, hence there's no need for a mic so I use Soundflower as the system output to create an audio sinkhole, like sending to `/dev/null`. When I export the movie (`File > Export > Movie`, and I've tried both `Slideshow Recording` and `Self Playing`) I get a silent film and any video or sound files that were in the presentation are just stills and do not play.

However, if I choose `Play > Play Recorded Slideshow` then everything is fine, the presentation movie plays with all the video and sounds all at the times I set them off. If I knew the location of that recording then I can ignore the export's strange ideas on how to process the recording and take that.

I've unzipped the .key file and found a file called `MovieRecording-XXX.mov` (where XXX is some kind of GUID) but it's really an audio track, and of course, it's mute. I can't find the whole video that is inside Keynote.

I've searched `~/Library` and I'm trying the temp directories but have found nothing so far. I have also looked through the data/metadata in the unzipped dirs and can't find a reference to it.

I'm actually about to try and make a screen recording of the one inside Keynote but that's obviously not ideal.

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Keynote v10.1
Mac v10.14.6

Comment: What Keynote version do you use? How did you export the movie file? Just to be sure: you "narrated" the presentation by embedding the narration as sound files?

Comment: @Gummibando I've added the info to the question, sorry about that. Yes, the narration already existed in audio form so was added as sound files. Neithe they nor the movie files will play when exported but do play via the `Play Recorded Slideshow` menu.